# Echo selected individual values from a 3 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I was hoping for some help with being able use a foreach() loop to 'echo' individual values from a three dimensional array.

Here is how the array is setup:

```
$_SESSION['cart']: Array
(
    [ZL] => Array
        (
            [mID] => ZL
            [mtitle] => Zoolander 2
            [mday] => Wednesday
            [mtime] => 6:00pm
            [seat] => Array
                (
                    [sa] => 1
                    [sp] => 1
                    [sc] => 2
                    [b1] => 1
                )

            [price] => $125.00
        )

)
```

And I am able to use the below to print every key and every value:

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $booking) { ?>
    <section>
        <?php foreach ($booking as $key => $value) { ?>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <?php if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value as $k=>$v){
            echo $k." > ".$v."<br/>";
            }
            } else { ?>
            <label><?php echo $key ?>:</label>
            <span><?php echo $value?></span>
            <?php } ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <?php } ?>
    </section>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

But I some of the value are only for processing, and I don't want them visable on the page.

I would also like to be able to have more descriptive 's.

How would I go about having an input similar to this:

```
Movie Title: Zoolander  ## [mtitle]
Day: Wednesday          ## [mday]
Time: 6:00pm            ## [mtime]

Ticket Type:

Adult: 12               ## [sa]
Pensioner: 1            ## [sp]
Child: 2                ## [sc]
Bean Bag: 1             ## [b1]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where are you getting stuck at? Which are the values to be hidden?

Comment: How to know which value is only for processing?

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala The only value to hide is the mID. I keep getting _Warning: Illegal string offset_ errors when I try and use individual '<?php echo $movie['mtitle'];?>'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $movie) { ?>
    <div>Movie Title: <?php echo $movie['mtitle'];?></div>
    <div>Day: <?php echo $movie['mday'];?></div>
    <div>Time: <?php echo $movie['mtime'];?></div>

    <p>Ticket Type:</p>

    <div>Adult: <?php echo $movie['seat']['sa'];?></div>
    <div>Pensioner: <?php echo $movie['seat']['sp'];?></div>
    <div>Child: <?php echo $movie['seat']['sc'];?></div>
    <div>Bean Bag: <?php echo $movie['seat']['b1'];?></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Output:

```
Movie Title: Zoolander 2
Day: Wednesday
Time: 6:00pm

Ticket Type:

Adult: 1
Pensioner: 1
Child: 2
Bean Bag: 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! It spits out an error when not all seats have a value, would I have make an If statement or something to make it not echo a nonexistent value?

Comment: Yes. You can set something like:
`echo isset($movie['seat']['sa']) ? $movie['seat']['sa'] : '';`

Comment: Thanks! You are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$test['ZL']['mID'] = 'ZL';
$test['ZL']['mtitle'] = 'Zoolander 2';
$test['ZL']['mday'] = 'Wednesday';
$test['ZL']['mtime'] = '6:00pm';
$test['ZL']['seat']['sa'] = 1;
$test['ZL']['seat']['sp'] = 1;
$test['ZL']['seat']['sc'] = 2;
$test['ZL']['seat']['b1'] = 1;
$test['ZL']['price'] = '$125.00';

?>
<div>
    <?php foreach ($test as $movie) { ?>
    <section>

        <ul>
            <li>Movie Title: <?php echo $movie['mtitle'];?></li>
            <li>Day: <?php echo $movie['mday'];?></li>
            <li>Time: <?php echo $movie['mtime'];?></li>
            <li>Ticket Type:</li>
            <li>Adult: <?php echo $movie['seat']['sa'];?></li>
            <li>Pensioner: <?php echo $movie['seat']['sp'];?></li>
            <li>Child: <?php echo $movie['seat']['sc'];?></li>
            <li>Bean Bag: <?php echo $movie['seat']['b1'];?></li>
        </ul>

    </section>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried doing that earlier and it keeps spitting out _Warning: Illegal string offset_ for each value I attempt to echo. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the example to be a minimal, verifiable, complete example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you. The array is being build by a <form> on a previous page, constructs it as the array and the $_GET to the confirmation page. So the information isn't always the same. Is it possible use the top PHP in this sort of way?

Comment: It should work the same with any array that's formatted like your example.